communication between jupyter notebook and javascript
I want to communicate between jupyter notebooks IPython and the javascript console in-notebook.
I really like this solution:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881349/cannot-get-jupyter-notebook-to-access-javascript-variables?rq=3#:~:text=display(Javascript(%22%22%22%0A%20%20const,%7D))%0Aprint(response)
However, this only works when the cells are split which will delayed by one cell run if used amongst other code in say a function for example.
So my question is about how to get this behavior to work without splitting the cells and then being capable of running this in a standalone function to enable communication.
i.e.
from IPython.core.display import Javascript

def get_js(eval: str="",exec: str="",timeout: int="") -> str:
    """
    Allows communication between jupyter notebooks IPython and javascript
    
    erpuntbakker (2019) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58881349/cannot-get-jupyter-notebook-to-access-javascript-variables?rq=3, CC BY-SA 4.0
    # changes made: condensd the core idea into a function for custom communication
    """
    if timeout: timeout=f",{timeout*10**3}"
    display(Javascript("""
      const CodeCell = window.IPython.CodeCell;
      CodeCell.prototype._handle_input_request = function(msg) {
          """+exec+"""
          setTimeout(() => { IPython.notebook.kernel.send_input_reply("""+eval+""") }"""+timeout+""")
      }
    """))
    return input({})

I've also considered this solution which seems interesting: Direct communication between Javascript in Jupyter and server via IPython kernel
But I'm yet to understand how it works and what a running example would be. Also, my version of jupyter notebook couldn't retrieve SHELL_PRIORITY so the solution would be incompatible for me.
Thank you
