# pandas : read_csv not accepting relative path

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have python code in Jupyter notebook and accompanying data in the same folder. I will be bundling both the code and data into a zip file and submitting for evaluation. I am trying to read the data inside the Notebook using pandas.read_csv using a relative path and thats not working. the API doesnt seem to work with relative path. What is the correct way to handle this?

Update:
My findings so far seem to suggest that, I should be using os.chdir() to set the current working directory. But I wouldn't know where the zip file will get extracted. The code is supposed to be read-only..So I cannot expect the receiver to update the path as appropriate.

Comment: It may not be possible in general, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52119454/how-to-obtain-jupyter-notebooks-path

Answer (score 3):

You could append the current working directory with the relative path to avoid problem as such:

```
import os
import pandas as pd

BASE_DIR = os.getcwd()
csv_path = "csvname.csv"

df = pd.read_csv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, csv_path)
```

where `csv_path` is the relative path.

Answer (score -1):

I think first of all you should make a unzip file then you can run.

> You may use the below code to unzip file,

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
file_name = "folder_name.zip"
 
with ZipFile(file_name, 'r') as zip:
  zip.extractall()
  print("Done !")
```