# How to load files in a notebook when using Snakemake?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, relative-path, snakemake

In a data processing project with several steps, using Snakemake, there is a Python Jupyter Notebook in a subdirectory that processes some data:

Notebook `processing_step_1/process.ipynb` contains:

```
with open('input.csv') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        print(line)
```

Data file `processing_step_1/input.csv` contains:

```
one,two,three
1,2,3
```

And this is the `Snakefile` using the `notebook` :

```
rule process_data:
    input:
        "processing_step_1/input.csv",
    notebook:
        "processing_step_1/process.ipynb"
```

If I run the notebook interactively, or from the command line like this

```
jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook processing_step_1/process.ipynb
```

it works. The working directory is set to the directory of the notebook and the input file can be found with a relative path.

When running from Snakemake, though, using

```
snakemake -c1
```

I get an error message

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'input.csv'
```

and the reason for that is that the notebook is copied and executed in a different directory, as can be seen from the Snakemake error message:

```
Command 'set -euo pipefail;  jupyter-nbconvert --log-level ERROR --execute  --to notebook --ExecutePreprocessor.timeout=-1 /path/to/project/.snakemake/scripts/tmp9mmr8k20.process.ipynb' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

What is the canonical way of loading data files from the same directory as the notebook when using Snakemake?

I would like to still be able to use the same notebook standalone without Snakemake. So preferably I wouldn’t like to add Snakemake-specific code to it.

It seems to be impossible to find the directory containing the notebook from within the notebook. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52119628/381281. Also I couldn’t find a way to set a working directory per rule in Snakemake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution by @hfs (OP) is one way to resolve this, but another way is to avoid hardcoding the file paths within the notebook:

```py
# with open('input.csv') as infile: <- this is hard-coded
with open(snakemake.input[0]) as infile: # this is flexible
   ...
```

Note that for this solution to work, the `notebook` directive should be used instead of the `shell`-`nbconvert` combination.

Answer (score 1):

Using `shell`, one can `cd` to the desired working directory:

```
rule process_data:
    input:
        "processing_step_1/input.csv",
    shell:
        """
        cd processing_step_1
        jupyter nbconvert --execute --to notebook --inplace process.ipynb
        """
```