# Why does os.path refer to the project path instead of file path?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Here is the structure of the folder:

```
- python
  - python study
    - study.py
    - a.txt
```

The code in study.py is:

```
import os

if(os.path.exists("a.txt")):
  print("YES") # my real code is not this
else:
  print("NO")
```

Usually I open the`python study` folder as pycharm project,like this:

[image: s]

And the result is `YES`.

But today I carelessly open the `python` folder(not `python study`) as pycharm project and run the code.
The result is `NO`. Finally,I find it refer to the `python`(project path) instead of the folder of the .py file.What's the purpose of this?

After this, I run this code in cmd,and the result is `YES`.
I think it some time will bring some problems while develop project with other people.(If someone use notepad instead of pycharm to edit code and run code in cmd).

Comment: I dont think this is an issue. You really need to know in which folder you are working in otherwise bigger issues might arrise than the script not running :)

Comment: os.path.exist("a.txt") will check it this file exist in the current folder where the script is ran out of.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786376/how-do-i-run-a-program-with-a-different-working-directory-from-current-from-lin

Comment: @marxmacher OK,it's true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you don't specify the absolute path of a file, it is assumed to be in the working directory.

When you open your project from the folder `python` that is the working directory and `os.path.exists('a.txt')` is actually looking for the file 'a.txt' in the folder `python`.

In order to make your script independant of the working directory. You should use relative paths.

You can use `__file__` to refer to your script. And you can get the directory of your script using `os.path.dirname`.

So I think you should modify your code to

```py
import os

fname = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'a.txt')

if(os.path.exists(fname)):
  print("YES")
else:
  print("NO")
```

Comment: actually it's preferred the use `os.path.abspath(__file__)` because `__file__` not always is an absolute path.

Comment: Using \_\_file\_\_ does not work in [Jupyter notebook as noted here with an alternate solution that's more universal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125532/file-does-not-exisit-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 1):

Edit: try this instead of simply calling the path exist, cause it should normalize absolutized version of the pathname path:

```
os.path.abspath(os.curdir)
```

By the way, according to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.exists), This function may return False if permission is not granted to execute os.stat() on the requested file, even if the path physically exists. So keep that in mind.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue being described

Comment: Posting comments as answers will not get you the reputation you need to comment.

Comment: @MadPhysicist ok, thanks for the heads up. I edited my answer... won't happen again :)