# name '__file__' is not defined in jupyter notebook

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter

I want to run this repository
https://github.com/werner-duvaud/muzero-general in jupyter notebook,  but when I copied all the code and upload all the file in jupyter, I have got this error:

```
os.listdir(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)) + "/games")
```

Should I use the clone ...? could help me to solve this problem? Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [\_\_file\_\_ does not exist in Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125532/file-does-not-exist-in-jupyter-notebook)

Answer (score 3):

The problem arise because of environment you are using. When you run python code in Jupyter notebook you are not running usual python environment - you are running it with iPython - interactive shell (version 7.12.0 is last currently). And it doesn't define hidden variable `__file__` as mainstream python environment does - so it doesn't understand where to look for '/games' folder.

What you could do:

1. Run it in usual python environment with '**file**' variable defined
2. Try placing your Jupyter notebook file in this project folder and using os.getcwd() instead of `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))` or change path any other way that suits you.