# NameError: name '__file__' is not defined for IMDP API TSV file

Tags: python

I have been trying to look at the IMDP API through this tsv file [https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz"](https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz%22). I however I am at a point where I keep on getting this error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-cfcd2677a0e6> in <module>
----> 1 TsvHandler("https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz")

<ipython-input-4-a2aea9b9f867> in __init__(self, url)
      4         # Example of download url: https://datasets.imdbws.com/title.basics.tsv.gz
      5         self.url = url
----> 6         data_dir = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.parent.parent.resolve()
      7         self.download_location = os.path.join(data_dir, "data/temp")  # "../../data/temp"
      8         self.filename = self.url.split('/')[-1]

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

Comment: `__file__` is only meaningful when you're running a script contained in an actual file.  You appear to be pasting code into a Python interactive prompt, which inherently has no filename associated with it.

Answer (score 0):

First, a Jupyter Notebook doesn't have a `__file__` variable, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39125532/9997212).

The first solution would be not running this code in a notebook: try creating a Python file (e.g. *filename.py*), copy the code you want to run into it and then run it using `python filename.py`.

In the case you must use a Jupyter Notebook, you have two approaches: if you *can* change the source code, change `__file__` to `os.path.abspath('')`. Otherwise, before calling the `TsvHandler` class, try defining a global variable  named `__file__` and assign it to `os.path.abspath('')`:

```
__file__ = os.path.abspath('')
TsvHandler("https://datasets.imdbws.com/name.basics.tsv.gz")
```