# how to access the name of a jupyter notebook from within that notebook

Tags: python, import, module, jupyter-notebook, filenames

I want to access the name of a jupyter notebook from within that juypyter notebook.
I need the name, because I want to import a small `.py` file containing some helper code. This `heatmap_axes.py` file is outside the folder, where the notebook is. So I am using an approach from [here](https://csatlas.com/python-import-file-module/?msclkid=301d0f72b66211ec915db62bcc4af66f#import_a_file_in_a_different_directory). This approach requires my to access the name of the current file with `__file__`, but that doesn't seem to work in the jupyter notebook.

That is the code:

```
script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
module_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, '..')
sys.path.append(module_dir)
from heatmap_axes import set_date_ticks
```

When I run the code, I get an error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_2232/3919301704.py in <module>
     21 from distutils.spawn import find_executable
     22 
---> 23 script_dir = os.path.dirname(__file__)
     24 module_dir = os.path.join(script_dir, '..')
     25 sys.path.append(module_dir)

NameError: name '__file__' is not defined
```

OK, I could write the name of the notebook on my own, but I need to import this helper `.py` file in several notebooks, so I want an automated solution. Copying the `.py` file inside the folder with the notebooks also is not an option, because I have many directories containg notebooks, and I don't want to have to copy this `.py` file in each of these directories.

That is, what the file-structure looks like:

```
heatmap_axes.py
nb01\
   <somenotebookname>.ipynb
    ...
nb02\
    <somenotebookname>.ipynb
    ...
nb03\
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**Solved:**

```
script_dir = os.path.abspath('')
```

found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39125532/file-does-not-exist-in-jupyter-notebook?msclkid=877a333db67111ecb981b8e82aa2f265).