# Jupyter - export current ipynb file to html within the notebook

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to write python code in my jupyter notebook, that will export the whole **current** notebook to html/pdf.

I know I can do something like that:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.call("jupyter nbconvert notebook.ipynb")
```

But that requires the file name, **which is not known inside the notebook**.

I saw many "hacks" to get the notebook file name, like this one: 
[How do I get the current IPython Notebook name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544056/how-do-i-get-the-current-ipython-notebook-name)
but I prefer to find a better solution.

Is there a smart way to export the current running notebook to a html/pdf file?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you just use the main menu `File > Download as... > HTML`?

Comment: I need to write a python package that will export the notebook automatically and save it in a specific location

Comment: Yeah, but *why* do you need to write a package that does it inside the notebook? I would recommend a workflow that stays outside of the notebook, and compiles everything from there.

Comment: In the end-state, I want this workflow to track finished runs of notebooks, export the whole notebook (including the outputs) to a html/pdf file, and save it in a remote directory, in order to keep track of running experiments.If I write a workflow that runs outside of the notebook, will it be possible to determine which notebook has finished it's run?

Comment: @ItayGabbay did you find a way to do it? :)

Comment: @mbh86 Unfortunately, No :(

Comment: @ItayGabbay By chance, I found a solution. I was looking for script to execute many notebooks in a row, with different parameters, and so I found a way to pass parameters from outside the notebooks, which also fits your need imho. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the library **papermill**, that will execute the notebook with ingested parameters (basically your notebook name that you define **outside your notebook**)

***Python program***

```
pm.execute_notebook(
   'notebooks/notebookA.ipynb', # notebook to execute
   'notebooks/temp.ipynb', # temporary notebook that will contains the outputs and will be used to save HTML
   report_mode=True, # To hide ingested parameters cells, but not working for me
   parameters=dict(filename_ipynb='notebooks/temp.ipynb', 
                   filename_html='output/notebookA.html')
)
```

***/notebooks/notebookA.ipynb***

*(To insert as the last cell of your notebook)*

```
import os
os.system('jupyter nbconvert --output ../' + filename_html + ' --to html ' + filename_ipynb)
```

Just a thing:
it is adding a cell to set the parameters ingested. It should be able to hide it with report_mode=False but somehow it doesn't work, even though it should: https://github.com/nteract/papermill/issues/253