# Can a jupyter notebook find its own filename?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter-lab, python-os

Is it possible for a jupyter notebook to get the name of its own file, similarly to what we would do from a python script?

`os.path.basename(__file__)` doesn't seem to work, at least for me on jupyterlab

`sys.argv[0]` returns `my_home/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ipykernel_launcher.py`

Comment: Have you tried doing what's suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30942416/9374673)?

Comment: I had not seen that, but when I try I get `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`

Comment: It works just fine for me. I just tested it with a random notebook I had. I'm not sure what the reason for that error is.

Comment: I tried in jupyter notebook (I was on jupyter lab), I don't get the same error and I can get the filename (which is what I had asked), but I cannot get the full path.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would get the full path or if it's even possible. I did see some others comment the same thing on that other post, but maybe someone else has some idea of how it could be done.

Comment: @Ziofil, can you please post the solution that worked for you. I have tried various of the javascript solutions suggested at the link Mihai Chelaru posted but none of them work for me. I get JavaScript errors for all of them. I am running Py 3.6, Jupyter 5.0 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I've found is through JavaScritp as in 
[this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23619544/2346377).

The compact form is a cell like this:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(`notebookName = '${window.document.getElementById("notebook_name").innerHTML}'`);
```

after that you'll have the variable `notebookName` with the name that appears at the 
top of the page.

A better solution may be using `IPython.notebook.notebook_name`:

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute(`notebookName = '${IPython.notebook.notebook_name}'`);
```

it gives you the name with the extension `.ipynb`

Comment: On jupyter lab I get the error `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined`

Comment: That was awesome!

Comment: Yup, `Javascript Error: IPython is not defined` on `jupyter lab : 3.0.14` and `jupyter core : 4.7.1`