# Save a copy of a notebook from within the notebook itself

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I would like to save a copy of a notebook (or rename it) from within a cell of the notebook.

Preferably without too much JavaScript. Actually I guess something of this form should work

```
from IPython.display import display_html
display_html("script>Jupyter....???...()</script>")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution only in Python. The `notebook_path` function comes from P.Toccaceli's solution on [How do I get the current IPython Notebook name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544056/how-do-i-get-the-current-ipython-notebook-name).

```
from notebook import notebookapp
import urllib
import json
import os
import ipykernel
from shutil import copy2

def notebook_path():
    """Returns the absolute path of the Notebook or None if it cannot be determined
    NOTE: works only when the security is token-based or there is also no password
    """
    connection_file = os.path.basename(ipykernel.get_connection_file())
    kernel_id = connection_file.split('-', 1)[1].split('.')[0]

    for srv in notebookapp.list_running_servers():
        try:
            if srv['token']=='' and not srv['password']:  # No token and no password, ahem...
                req = urllib.request.urlopen(srv['url']+'api/sessions')
            else:
                req = urllib.request.urlopen(srv['url']+'api/sessions?token='+srv['token'])
            sessions = json.load(req)
            for sess in sessions:
                if sess['kernel']['id'] == kernel_id:
                    return os.path.join(srv['notebook_dir'],sess['notebook']['path'])
        except:
            pass  # There may be stale entries in the runtime directory 
    return None


  def copy_current_nb(new_name):
    nb = notebook_path()
    if nb:
        new_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(nb), new_name+'.ipynb')
        copy2(nb, new_path)
    else:
        print("Current notebook path cannot be determined.")
```

Then, simply use `copy_current_nb('Save1')` to create a copy named `Save1.ipynb` in the same directory.

Comment: srv['notebook_dir'] is for me, every time, Anaconda's script folder.