# Getting the file name of an ipython notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, ipython

For python files I can get the file name and use to as a prefix for the generated results using:

```
prefix = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(main.__file__))[0]
```

But this fails for ipython notebooks with the following error:

```
---> 23     return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(main.__file__))[0]
AttributeError: module '__main__' has no attribute '__file__'
```

Is there a reasonable way to get the current notebook's name?

Previously suggested solutions, like [ipyparams](https://pypi.org/project/ipyparams/) and [ipynbname](https://pypi.org/project/ipynbname/) don't seem to work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Someone already posted a workaround using JavaScript.
You can find the original question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44589075

Comment: Nothing from there seems to work.

Comment: This should be a comment actually.

Answer (score 0):

Or you could do it by using the `__session__` global variables:

```
import os
os.path.basename(globals()['__session__'])
```

You may even just use `__session__` in a naked cell.

Here's even a more elegant way:

[How do I get the current IPython / Jupyter Notebook name - "jupyter_session" get_connect_file()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78012219/23145088)