# How can I save .py text version of jupyter notebook from the notebook itself

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, nbconvert

I want to save a text version (`.py`) of a Jupyter notebook (`.ipynb`) without output for version control purposes.

I know you can do this by running `jupyter nbconvert` in terminal, but how can I automate this by executing this command from within the Jupyter notebook itself?

Also see
[Using IPython / Jupyter Notebooks Under Version Control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18734739/using-ipython-jupyter-notebooks-under-version-control)

Comment: Installing [Jupytext](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) (the [repo](https://github.com/mwouts/jupytext/tree/main)) also adds more features for making `.py` files from within Jupyter itself and using jupytext similar to on the command line by putting an exclamation point in front of the Jupytext [command line](https://jupytext.readthedocs.io/en/latest/using-cli.html) commands for running them from within an `.ipynb` cell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save a text version (`.py`) of the notebook by adding this cell at the top of your Jupyter notebook. The Python file will be saved in the same folder. You can specify `--output-dir` if you like.

```py
import os

nb_name = "mynotebook1.ipynb" #TODO change this to the file name of your Jupyter notebook

basename, ext = os.path.splitext(nb_name)
input_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), nb_name)

!jupyter nbconvert "{input_path}" --to="python" --output="{basename}"
```

---

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12544056/how-do-i-get-the-current-ipython-jupyter-notebook-name), the following also work with 2 cells

First cell

```
%%javascript
IPython.notebook.kernel.execute('nb_name = "' + IPython.notebook.notebook_name + '"')
```

Second cell

```py
import os

basename, ext = os.path.splitext(nb_name)
input_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), nb_name)

!jupyter nbconvert "{input_path}" --to="python" --output="{basename}"
```

---

If you use this tool, you can make it with just one cell
https://pypi.org/project/ipynbname/

```py
import ipynbname
import os

nb_name= ipynbname.name()

basename, ext = os.path.splitext(nb_name)
input_path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), nb_name)

!jupyter nbconvert "{input_path}" --to="python" --output="{basename}"
```